# Export Javascript object to be used in other files?

Tags: javascript, import, export

I have a utils.js file which contains utilities for a bunch of different things. Now, if I have a function, say:

```
function toDateString(epochSec) {
    var date = new Date(epochSec*1000);
    return date.toString();
}
```

I can simply export it by stating `export default toDateString` in the end of the file, and in another file, write `import toDateString from './utils.js'` That's understood.

However, how do I export the following object in a similar manner, to use it in another file?

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype,'fileSize',{value:function(a,b,c,d){
    return (a=a?[1e3,'k','B']:[1024,'K','iB'],b=Math,c=b.log,
            d=c(this)/c(a[0])|0,this/b.pow(a[0],d)).toFixed(2)
        +' '+(d?(a[1]+'MGTPEZY')[--d]+a[2]:'Bytes');
},writable:false,enumerable:false});
```

I'd rather not copy-paste this object into a bunch of other .js files since I use it quite often. How do I call it from another file in a similar manner to the exported functions as shown above?

Comment: You are trying to modify Number.prototype. You do not need to call it multiple times. Just call it once on your app entry, then you will have that feature  globally

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thanks.